# Rebuild only code in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have quite big yii2 application that takes a few minutes to build in docker. Is there a way to build code only, without "re-installing" everything each time? How do I speed up developing/debugging of dockerized yii2 app?

Now I do this:

> docker build -t myapp:mytag .
>   docker run --name myapp -p 8000:8000 myapp:mytag

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

COPY . /var/www/html/

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/web

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl nano unzip zlib1g-dev git && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install


RUN cd /var/www/html/ && mkdir web/assets/
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/web/assets/

RUN mv /var/www/html/vendor/bower-asset/ /var/www/html/vendor/bower/
```

Comment: Just create a base image where you install everything you need. Then you use a separate image which depends on your base image and just adds your code

Comment: In my case, I just use [--mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#choosing-the--v-or-mount-flag) option for code directory on debugging and testing phase so that I don't need to rebuild the image and I just fix the code and run again without any additional steps. after then when I need to release the image I build the whole image including code directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker will reused cached build steps that it has previously performed and have not changed. However, once you reach a step that breaks the cache, all subsequent steps have to rerun since the cache includes a dependency on the previous step. Therefore, the cache is order dependent and you have the following as one of your very first steps:

```
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Every time you change your code, that line will have to be rerun, which then forces the `apt-get` lines to rerun as well. By reordering your install you'll see a large speed up:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/web

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl nano unzip zlib1g-dev git && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# move this line to as late in the build as possible
COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install

RUN cd /var/www/html/ && mkdir web/assets/
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/web/assets/

RUN mv /var/www/html/vendor/bower-asset/ /var/www/html/vendor/bower/
```

Comment: Dose `docker` detect if the code is changed or not when running `COPY` command even without any change of `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @SangminKim It uses a hash of the file contents to detect changes. So even without changing the Dockerfile, docker will know to rerun the `COPY` command. The same does not hold true if you were to `RUN curl ... >external-file.txt` since docker only looks at the command, not everything that command externally depends on.

Comment: NOTE: I did a little bit of cheating: before `
RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install` I copied everything except folders 'controllers', 'models', 'views'. I copied these three folders as a very last step - now it builds super quickly after changes, thank you very much for help!